# Visual Studio Project template add packages.config without downloading Nugets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-templates

I have .vstemplate file which has a reference to the Nuget like this:

```
 <WizardExtension>
     <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
     <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
 </WizardExtension>
```

The default behavior is that VisualStudio will go online, get needed packages, create packages.config and put references in there. But if you are offline, VisualStudio will throw an exception saying he cannot find packages and will not create package.config.

Now, is it possible to override that behavior? I want to get packages.config file regardless of the VisualStduio ability to download packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to override that behavior?

The answer for this questions is negative.
As we know the [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/packages-config), The packages.config file is used in some project types to maintain the list of packages referenced by the project. If we install package to the project, nuget will add the packages.config to the project automatically. If you do not have any packages installed, the packages.config will **not** be added. This is the default behavior of nuget. It is so designed.

Besides, as far as I know for the template with preinstalled packages, to add preinstalled packages to your project template you need to:
1. Edit your vstemplate file and add a reference to the NuGet template wizard by adding a WizardExtension element
2. Add the list of packages to install in the project

There is no override for nuget default behavior. So If you want to override the nuget default behavior via Visua Studio template is not possible.

As a suggestion, your question is about challenging the design of nuget, you can ask this question on the [GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home).